# Vagrant flask app reload very slow

Tags: python, flask, vagrant, virtualenv

I've got rather small flask application which I run using:

```
$ python wsgi.py
```

When editing files, server reloads on each file save. This reload takes even up to 10sec. 
That's system section from my Virtual Box:

```
Base: 2048Mb,
Memory:
Processors: 4
Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX
```

How can I speed it up, or where do I look for issues?

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code.

Comment: The whole application is around 100 files... so it would be difficult to show the code. Even when I don't modify files it takes few seconds for server to get up after $ python wsgi.py - which makes me think that it's not code related but some settings issue

Comment: Have you tried running a basic hello world application to rule out the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be virtualenv being sync'd too.

I stumbled upon the same problem, and the issue was that VirtualBox's default synchronization implementation is very very slow when dealing with too many files in the mounted directory. Upon investigating, I found:

```
$ cd my-project 
$ tree | tail -n 1
220 directories, 2390 files
```

That looks like too many files for a simple flask project, right? So, as it turns out, I was putting my virtualenv directory inside my project directory too, meaning everything got sync'ed.

```
$ cd my-project/env
203 directories, 2313 files
$ cd my-project
$ rm -Rf my-project/env
$ tree | tail -n 1 
17 directories, 77 files
```

Now it looks much more manageable and indeed much faster. Sure, we still need to store the virtualenv somewhere, but it actually makes much more sense to create it somewhere *inside* the guest machine, and not mounted against the host - specially if you consider that the host and the guest could be different OS's anyway.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the file system for NFS. I had this problem, I switched to NFS and has been fixed.

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
```

[ENABLING NFS SYNCED FOLDERS](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/nfs.html)